# Play audio from NSData in a library in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play an audio content built from NSData inside a library (.a).
It works properly when my code is inside an app.
But it is not working when in a library, I get no error and no sound playing.

```
NSError * errorFile;
NSError * errorAudio = nil;

// Clear all cache
NSArray* tmpDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:NULL];
for (NSString *file in tmpDirectory) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), file] error:NULL];
}

// Set temporary directory and temporary file
NSURL * tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];
NSURL * soundFileURL = [[tmpDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"wav"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:tmpDirURL withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&errorFile];

// Write NSData to temporary file
NSString *path= [soundFileURL path];
[audioToPlay writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&errorFile];

// Init audio player
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&errorAudio];

if (errorAudio) {
    // Audio player could not be initialized
} else {
    // Audio player was initialized correctly
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer setCurrentTime:0];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

My header file

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@property(nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer;
```

My m file

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@synthesize audioPlayer;
```

I've been checking for dozens of posts but cannot find any solution, it always works properly in an app, but not in a library.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You did not check the `errorFile`

Comment: True, I don't check it in the code, but when debugging, I could see `errorFile` is `nil`